# configuring rds without having a domain

Tags: windows-server-2012

How to configure  Active Directory Domain Services Configuration if i dont have a domain.

problem statement
I have a server and i want to install RDS inorder to have session based virtualisation so that 5-6 users can access this server .

so i wanted to install RDS from adding roles and features. when i start this process i get an
error saying local server must be joined to the domain to complete the RDS installation

please help me out

Comment: So this question is a little confusing. Are you asking for help setting up RDS without a domain, or for help creating a domain that you can use to complete your RDS install?

Comment: i wanted to create a domain and then complete RDS install. I hope that i have created a domain using ad ds wizard.

Answer (score 0):

RDS *requires* the server to be a domain member for this scenario. If I recall correctly, it won't behave properly on a domain controller either, so it needs to specifically be a domain member server.

Therefore, what I would suggest if this is a physical server, is installing a DC and the RDS server as two different virtualised servers on top of a HyperV host. If that doesn't work for you then you may need to completely re-think what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: robm what i have done is i promoted my server to be the domain controller using active directory domain service configuration. I want to ask you , if i can go and change my server to the domain that i have created and then go ahead installing RDS

Comment: If you've promoted the server you were trying to install RDS on to a DC then you don't need to make that server a member of the domain - Domain Controllers are always members of their own domains, if you see what I mean. As for installing RDS on the DC, you can certainly install some of the roles, maybe even all of them (I'm not sure offhand), so by all means have a go. I'd still say you'd be better off creating two virtual servers using HyperV and splitting the DC and RDS roles up, depending on what the 6 users who you're trying to give access to are planning to do with that access.

Comment: RobM thanks a lot for answering these questions. I am a novice in this field. So my questions may seem very childish. I want to give these users access to only certain applications.for ex nodejs to one particular user and some other app to someone else. I dont want them to do a RDP to the server. So i want to create a session virtualization and provide restricted access.

Comment: @shiva in that case I'd definitely go back to setting this up with separate servers in hyperv.

Comment: Is this a new requirement of 2012?

Comment: @KeithStokes Not sure exactly but I know that RDS in general had a pretty big overhaul for 2012. We're sticking with 2008r2 for our RDS servers at the moment as we don't want to inflict the windows 8 desktop on our users.